# How to set autoload from "yes" to "no" _transient_wp_core_block_css_files

Tags: block-editor, phpmyadmin, transient

In WordPress version 6.3, create a transient named "_transient_wp_core_block_css_files" (~0.4MB) in the wp_options table to store the list of CSS files to load when using WordPress' blocks. When the site loads and needs to use the block, WordPress checks this transient to determine if the CSS files need to be loaded.

I don't use the block. I tried to set autoload from "yes" to "no" but failed:

1. I try to change yes to no in phpmyadmin but no success.
2. I try this in funtions.php but no success.
   add_filter( 'block_styles_should_load', '__return_false' );
   delete_transient( '_transient_wp_core_block_css_files' );

Do you know any better way?

Comment: actually you do, there is no `wp_core_block` it's for _all_ core blocks, be that headings, paragraphs, etc etc, by changing this to autoload false you'll be reducing performance by making it do a second small DB query to fetch its value. I know you're hoping to reduce weight and make things faster/cleaner but you're actually doing the opposite unintentionally!

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother messing the with `autoload` on the transient. If you're truly not using blocks at all, just unhook the function that creates the transient and uses it to register the style handles:

```
remove_action( 'init', 'register_core_block_style_handles', 9 );
```

Just be aware that if you *do* use blocks, their stylesheets will not load until you let WordPress create the transient again.

Comment: Thank Jacob Peattie!

Comment: It is not working for me.  _transient_wp_core_block_css_files
: 46832

Answer (score 0):

It is work for me.

```php
function remove_core_block_style_handles() {
    remove_action( 'init', 'register_core_block_style_handles', 9 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_core_block_style_handles' );


if ( function_exists( 'delete_transient' ) ) {
    delete_transient( 'wp_core_block_css_files' );
}
```